# Designing profile boxes with bootstrap's grid system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm trying to modify this [bootstrap snippet](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/user-profile-widget) so that it looks like my image below, where B, C, D, E are all the same size with A a little bit larger. I'm trying to use this for my profile section on my website (which explains the inner boxes for the images).

I'm having a lot of troubles with the grid system though. Either the text misaligns when I insert an image or the boxes won't come side by side.

Here's my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nv7rsgpg/8/

[image: user profile]

Can anyone help me out!? Or possibly direct me to another framework that could be easier than doing it by hand?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Stylish Portfolio - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio/css/stylish-portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<style>

    body{padding-top:30px;}

.glyphicon {  margin-bottom: 10px;margin-right: 10px;}

small {
display: block;
line-height: 1.428571429;
color: #999;
}
    </style>


</head>

<body>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                    <div class="well well-sm">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                <img src="" alt="" class="img-rounded img-responsive" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                                <h4>
                                    Person</h4>
                                <small><cite title="San Francisco, USA">USA <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">
                                </i></cite></small>
                                <p>
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>email@example.com
                                    <br />
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">www.jquery2dotnet.com</a>
                                    <br />
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></i>June 02, 1988</p>
                                <!-- Split button -->
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Social</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        <span class="caret"></span><span class="sr-only">Social</span>
                                    </button>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/+Jquery2dotnet/posts">Google +</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/jquery2dotnet">Facebook</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Github</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/380x500" alt="" class="img-rounded img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                        <h4>
                            Bhaumik Patel</h4>
                        <small><cite title="San Francisco, USA">San Francisco, USA <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">
                        </i></cite></small>
                        <p>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>email@example.com
                            <br />
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">www.jquery2dotnet.com</a>
                            <br />
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></i>June 02, 1988</p>
                        <!-- Split button -->
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Social</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="caret"></span><span class="sr-only">Social</span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                                <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/+Jquery2dotnet/posts">Google +</a></li>
                                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/jquery2dotnet">Facebook</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Github</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script>
    // Closes the sidebar menu
    $("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });

    // Opens the sidebar menu
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });

    // Scrolls to the selected menu item on the page
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not([href=#myCarousel])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It will be easier if you will code it base on the default of bootstrap rather than using that snippet. Just use the **responsive grid layout** of bootstrap to do that.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi there**, I have set up a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/2g73r4g3/)** with a grid layout as per your picture.

See if you can take this code here and use it as a good starting point.

You will need to view this in the **full view** if using the snippet view below or view the fiddle.
It will stack in the small screen size.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-color: darkcyan;  
}
.block {
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 2%;  
}
.inner-block {
  height: 280px;
  margin-top: 10px; 
}     
.bg-orange { 
  background-color: orangered;
}
.space{
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class="container col-lg-12"><br><br></div>
    <div class="container col-lg-12">

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 bg-orange block">
    <div class="row-fluid col-xs-4 col-sm-3 bg-primary inner-block">
        
    </div>
</div>
        
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 bg-orange block">
    <div class="row-fluid col-xs-4 col-sm-3 bg-primary inner-block">
        
    </div>
</div>
        
<div class="container col-lg-12 space"></div>
    
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 bg-orange block">
    <div class="row-fluid col-xs-4 col-sm-3 bg-primary inner-block">
        
    </div>
</div>
        
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 bg-orange block">
    <div class="row-fluid col-xs-4 col-sm-3 bg-primary inner-block">
        
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 bg-orange block">
    <div class="row-fluid col-xs-4 col-sm-3 bg-primary inner-block">
        
    </div>
</div>          
    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```